# Computer Vision: Image Comparison and Counting?

Tags: c++, python, c, opencv, computer-vision

I was curious if it would be possible to count the number of things in a picture, let's say the number of ducks, by first taking a sample picture and then seeing where it matched in a separate picture. So to clarify, we would have 2 pictures (one picture with a single duck, and one picture with 4 ducks for the sake of the argument) and the program would see how many matches it could make in the 4 duck picture by overlaying the one duck picture--thereby counting how many ducks there are in the picture. I've been reading up on computer vision a little bit, and I know that opencv's site talked about using a Fourier transform to break an image into its magnitude and phase. I was hoping to possibly take the magnitude of the one duck picture into a matrix and then compare it to a series of matrices from the four duck picture.

I imagine this would be quite difficult, seeing as how I would have to somehow tell the program the shape of the initial duck and then store that duck's broken down image information into a matrix and then compare that to matrices broken down from the other picture. Any ideas/suggestions? I thought this would be a good learning experience, since I'm an electrical engineering student and I learned Fourier Transforms, DFTs, etc. last semester--it'd just be cool to actually apply them to something.

Comment: Look for face detection and haar classifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about **object recognition** - one of fundamental problems in computer vision. Your main idea - take a picture of the object, get some features from it and then find same set of features on other image - is correct. However, pixel by pixel comparison (no matter in time or frequency domain) is very error-prone and normally gives poor results. In most cases more high-level features give much better results.

To get started, take a look at [**Cascade Classifier**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) in OpenCV which uses Haar-like features (small rectangles with particular gray level). It is most well-known for face detection and recognition, but can also be trained for other objects.

You may also be interested in [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF) method, which searches for points with similar characteristics, or even [AAMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model), which try to model shape and appearance of an object.